# Facing issue in making this in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

**My current code :**

```
Container(
                  height: 1 / 3 * deviceSize.height,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Text(
                    'Add New Location',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0),
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.elliptical(300, 100),
                        bottomRight: Radius.elliptical(300, 100)),
                    color: Color(0xFFFAD02E),
                  ),
                )
```

I am not getting desired results.... :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **`ClipPath`**

Try this

```
ClipPath(
  clipper: BottomClipper(),
  child: Container(
  height: 200,
  color: Colors.yellow,
  child: Center(child: Text("BottomClipper()")),
 ),
),
```

> BottomClipper()

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomClipper  extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - 40);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width / 4, size.height, size.width / 2, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width - size.width / 4, size.height, size.width, size.height - 40);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: brother, how can I make it fixed in the background so that I could use listView with physics: BouncingScrollPhysics()... and add the all the other widgets... while gesturing from upside down or downside up... the background ClipPath[you code] stays fixed in the background.... PLEASE tell

Answer (score 4):

You can Try **ClipPath** using custom clipper to make this desire UI in flutter. But Your Method can still work need some tweaking.

```js
ClipPath(
  clipper: ProfileClipper(),
  child: Image(
    height: 300.0,
    width: double.infinity,
    image: AssetImage('You can use image or your desire color use container'),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
),
```

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProfileClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, 4 * size.height / 5);
    Offset curvePoint = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height);
    Offset endPoint = Offset(size.width, 4 * size.height / 5);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      curvePoint.dx,
      curvePoint.dy,
      endPoint.dx,
      endPoint.dy,
    );
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```